# tkinter message box calling function

Tags: python, tkinter, messagebox

I want to display the title of the label in my messagebox which will display like "you have selected project". How can I do it with all of them like with save and exit also only using one function?

```
from tkinter import*

import tkinter.messagebox

root = Tk()

def func(label):
      tkinter.messagebox.askquestion("Information", "you have selected: ", label )


mymenu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu = mymenu)

submenu = Menu(mymenu)

mymenu.add_cascade(label = "file", menu = submenu)
submenu.add_command(label ="project", command = func)
submenu.add_command(label = "save", command = func)
submenu.add_separator()
submenu.add_command(label ="exit", command = func)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: rename the function argument to `func(event)` then instead of having `label` in the `askquesiton` part, get it from the submenu like this `submenu.get(<getTheSelectedPartFrom event??>)` print out the argument `event` to learn more.

Comment: Sorry, there is no `event` for this, so you can safely ignore my comment above.

Comment: @rocksteady I think this is because it would be redundant with the `command` option. The event that exists is `<<MenuSelect>>` and is triggered when the active (i.e. under the mouse) menu item changes.

Comment: Intuitively, I thought of it to provide something like `submenu.get(submenu.selected_item())`... I should have read about it before writing the comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with lambda functions (for the submenu commands) and [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html):

```
from tkinter import *

import tkinter.messagebox

root = Tk()

def func(label):
    tkinter.messagebox.askquestion("Information", "you have selected: {}".format(label))


mymenu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu = mymenu)

submenu = Menu(mymenu)

mymenu.add_cascade(label="file", menu=submenu)
submenu.add_command(label="project", command=lambda: func("project"))
submenu.add_command(label= "save", command=lambda: func("save"))
submenu.add_separator()
submenu.add_command(label="exit", command=lambda: func("exit"))

root.mainloop()
```

The lambda functions are used to pass the label argument corresponding to the submenu item to `func`.

For the messagebox, the syntax is `tkinter.messagebox.askquestion(<title>, <message>)`, so you need to insert the label argument inside your message with string formatting: `"you have selected: {}".format(label)`, th `{}` is replaced by the content of the `label` variable.